# OpenCL clgetPlatformID access violation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencl, amd-gpu, amd-app

I'm trying to learn some OpenCL to use in my OpenGL project to help speed up everything but I am currently stuck trying to get OpenCL to start. When I launch the program from Visual Studio 2015 the code breaks at `clGetPlatformIDs` with an access violation executing location `0x0000000`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cl_uint numPlatforms;   //the NO. of platforms
    cl_platform_id platform = NULL; //the chosen platform
    cl_int  status = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
}
```

I have a Windows 7 laptop with an Intel i7-2670QM and a Radeon HD 6490M. I installed the AMD APP SDK 3.0 prior to this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok first off for everyone in the future the only thing you need to do is check the Intel's, AMD's, and Nvdia's website for their most recent drivers for your GPU and CPU. No matter what they say there should be a driver and not a driver utility. The driver utility will say there up to date but there not. Find the drivers and then install them. You may need to pick up GPU-Z and GPU Caps to check that OpenCL is installed and working. Once that is done everything should be working. I also choose to use AMD APP SDK instead of Intel OpenCL SDK because I had it installed before and it crashed Visual Studio.

Comment: The self extracting driver from intel may not allow installation of later drivers for a work arround see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54751278/5440606